# What is the use of new keyword in javascript

Tags: javascript

```
var createworker = function() {

    var workcount;
    var input;
    (function() {
        workcount = 0;
        console.log("hello");
    }());
    var task1 = function() {
        workcount += 1;
        console.log("task1" + workcount);
    };
    var task2 = function(a) {
        workcount += 1;
        input = a;
        console.log("task2" + workcount + "variable" + a);
    };
    var task3 = function() {
        console.log(input);
    };

    return {
        job1: task1,
        job2: task2,
        job3: task3
    };
}

var worker = new createworker();
worker.job1();
worker.job2(2);
worker.job3();

var worker1 = createworker();
worker1.job1();
worker1.job2(2);
worker1.job3();
```

Both work same. Then why to use new and when to use it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3658673/2813224

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the 'new' keyword in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1646698/what-is-the-new-keyword-in-javascript)

Comment: Side note: That anonymous immediately-invoked function at the top of `createworker` is pointless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Both work same.

They reason they both work the same is that you're returning an object from `createworker`. That overrides the work that `new` did.

`new` is used with *constructor functions*. It does this:

1. Creates a new object backed by the object the constructor function's `prototype` property points ot
2. Calls the constructor function with `this` referring to that new object
3. In the normal case, the result of `new functionname` is a reference to the object that `new` created. **But**, if the constructor function returns a non-`null` object reference, the result of the `new` expression is that object *instead*. It's that "but" that's happening in your `createworker` example.

So your version of `createworker` doesn't need `new`, because of the way it's written.

And doing it that way is absolutely fine; in fact, there are people who always do it that way. If you wanted to use `new` with `createworker`, here's a version designed to be used that way (renamed `CreateWorker`, because by convention constructor functions are capitalized):

```
var CreateWorker = function() {

    var workcount;
    var input;
    (function() {               // Side note: This function is pointless. Just move
        workcount = 0;          // <− this line
        console.log("hello");   // <− and this one
    }());                       // ...out into the body of `createworker`/`CreateWorker`

    // Note we assign to properties on `this`
    this.job1 = function() {
        workcount += 1;
        console.log("task1" + workcount);
    };
    this.job2 = function(a) {
        workcount += 1;
        input = a;
        console.log("task2" + workcount + "variable" + a);
    };
    this.job3 = function() {
        console.log(input);
    };

    // Note we aren't returning anything
};
```